# Suppress css styles

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a link share from the third party website to display it in my site . But I need to get rid of some of the text in there Example the Share button. I tried suppressing by adding display:none to these but my CSS is getting overridden from their site.

One question running thru my mind.
First of all, Can I do that?

```
I have all my html contents here and then comes these div tags

    <div id="myDIVHERE">
    <div class="infogram-embed"
        data-id="1c09a6f5-16d8-4bf7-8769-9875b9569639" data-type="interactive"
        data-title="CPI 2017 World Map"></div>
    <script>
        !function(e, t, n, s) {
            var i = "InfogramEmbeds", o = e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], d = 
    /^http:/
                .test(e.location) ? "http:" : "https:";
        if (/^\/{2}/.test(s) && (s = d + s), window[i] && window[i].initialized)
            window[i].process && window[i].process();
        else if (!e.getElementById(n)) {
            var a = e.createElement(t);
            a.async = 1, a.id = n, a.src = s, o.parentNode.insertBefore(a, o)
        }
    }(document, "script", "infogram-async",
            "https://e.infogram.com/js/dist/embed-loader-min.js");
    </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you getting data from this third party site? Are you reading it in with ajax?

Comment: I have corrected my question. Not importing data. It is the shared link which they have provided in the site , i am using

Comment: is your css implemented correctly? try adding an element to the page, give it your own made up class and change it with your css if your style still does not appear you probably implemented it incorrectly

Comment: It looks that embedding scripts from infogram.com generate the `<iframe>` element, which is actually the separate document. So the short answer to your question is "it's impossible with CSS".

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn if it is impossible with CSS, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After taking a closer look at the generated script, it appears that the information is presented in an *iframe*.  In addition, this page is not a page on your domain, but is an external page.  Therefore, you cannot directly modify the style of the script with CSS, unfortunately.

As a note, it is possible to edit directly if the embedded site is on the same parent domain.

Comment: How are you importing this data, is it through an IFrame?

Comment: No I am not using iFrame. I have corrected my question, it is not importing data,it is just getting the link form that site and trying to use it my site

Comment: That script you have above, did you create that, or is it the script from the link sharing website?

Comment: Got it from the site , https://www.transparency.org/news/feature/corruption_perceptions_index_2017

Comment: Just updated my answer, looks like it isn't possible what you are trying to do with the CSS.

Comment: @BrandonDixon could you add the fact that it is possible in one way to adjust the css of an Iframe to your answer, being: The iframe css can be overwritten if the content is from the same parent domain. Because you make it sound like it can never be done if you use an Iframe.

Comment: @BrandonDixon, Thanks for your answer. Is there any way we can achieve this apart from trying to change the CSS?

Comment: My only other idea would be to try and look at the HTML rendered in the IFrame after the script has executed, then see if you can include that directly (so include the HTML of the iframe minus whatever you want to leave behind).  No guarantee it will work, and be aware, that might violate some sort of terms of service.